What does "it" in "make it work" refer to?
Marcus hears the song "Beyond the Sea" playing on the radio. Emmett says it has been airing continuously for four months, and he also mentions the location of the radio tower:

Emmett: It's the valley. I tried the radio from our house too, but we
never heard anything until we got up here. Your dad was never gonna
make it work.
Regan: You're nothing like him!

What does "it" in "make it work" refer to?

This seems to be a question relating to basic English comprehension. Had you thought about joining our sister-site, [ell.se]? You may find it to be of great help. ("it" in this case referring to the site I recommended).

It is the radio.

In this case "it" is the radio. I've not watched the film, but from the dialogue you posted in the question Emmett is making a deduction that the radio wasn't working at his place and at Reagan's place because of being in a valley where the signal is blocked by the surrounding hills.

Emmett: It's the valley. I tried the radio from our house too, but we never heard anything (on the radio) until we got up here. Your dad was never gonna make it (the radio) work

The reason for this is that the radio in this case is probably a Frequency Modulation signal or similar Very High Frequency signal, which only really work on a line-of-sight basis. This means that you need a clear line of transmission between transmitter and receiver. Objects like hills can block the signal so that you wouldn't hear anything in a valley unless there was a way to reflect/re-transmit the signal down into that location.
